# Are questions similar to this one on-topic on Seasoned Advice?

Tags: discussion, scope, questions

I read, [How do I color an egg black?](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/16948/how-do-i-color-an-egg-black) and I was wondering if such questions are on-topic.

Essentially the question is about how to get a black hollowed egg that is then filled with powdered material, which means:

- the egg is not used as food
- the question is not about food safety
- the question is not about tools used for cooking
- the question is not about a recipe

Comment: It did seem slightly off topic to me, but I am still learning the culture of this site.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, it's off topic because it's not about something that people will reasonably be expected to  eat.

Similarly off topic would be:

- Questions about [sugar glass](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sugar_glass)
- How to make Caro syrup and food dye look more like zombie blood?
- How to prepare food for food photography?
- How to make homemade play-dough?
- How to make a salt sculpture?

Comment: The zombie blood one would be ok for a gory cake, but not for a haloween costume.

Comment: Good point. I was thinking zombie blood when used as a costume / special effect.

Comment: I know. I only bring it up because of a friends awesome wedding.